# Как получить количество записей перед определенной записью в mysql с сортировкой по полю varchar?

Tags: mysql

Имею таблицу откуда беру запросом данные, и при определенных действиях, мне надо сделать подсчет количества записей перед определенной записью.
Но обязательно с сортировкой по полю varchar asc.

Сейчас я сделал так что в цикле прохожу по всем записям через limit и offset в php, пока это работает и быстро когда количество записей не особо много, а когда будет 100 тыс или больше, то, думаю этот процесс займет долгое время.

Есть ли возможность сделать это запросом в mysql?

Comment: А что насчёт записей, у которых в этом поле NULL? учитывать, нет?

Answer (score 1):

> мне надо сделать подсчет количества записей перед определенной записью.
> Но обязательно с сортировкой по полю varchar asc.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE varchar_column <= @value_in_definite_row
```

Или строгое неравенство, если саму "определённую запись" не учитывать.